# To display when we get the value from plist ,to only display login page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have created a main page with three buttons on it.
I have assigned values 0,1,2 to these buttons.
When the user clicks on a button, its value is written in a programmatically created plist file.

I can successfully fetch these values from the plist file and print on to the log.
Now when the user clicks button1 I want to hide the main page and show a login page.
If the plist file is deleted, clicking on button1 should continue showing the main page.

Please, can anyone provide some code or clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//function to write into plist
-(void)WriteFileToPlist:(int) num
{    
//write everything in the plist

    NSString *errorDesc;
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:strArray format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    if (plistData) {
        [plistData writeToFile:[self savePathForFile:num] atomically:YES];            
    }
}

//save the path
-(NSString *) savePathForFile:(int) num
{
    NSArray *pathArray = 
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myPlist%d.plist",num]];
}

//get the data from plist
- (NSArray *) GetFileDataFromPlist:(NSString *) fileName
{   
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //see if Data.plist exists in the Documents directory
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self savePath:fileName] ]) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[self savePath:@""] error:nil];
    }

    NSData *plistData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  contentsAtPath:[self savePath:fileName]];
    NSString *error; NSPropertyListFormat format;
    NSArray *heats = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData
                                                      mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                format:&format
                                                      errorDescription:&error];
    if (!heats) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to read myPlist. Error: %@", error);
        [error release];
    }
    return heats;
}

//getting the data form the saved path.
-(NSString *) savePath:(NSString *) fileName
{
    NSArray *pathArray = 
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myPlist%@.plist",fileName]];
}
```

when you tap on the second button remove the first button view from the superview and then load the view which is linked to the second button click.

You can present the view using presentModalViewController..

I hope this will help.